# How to use collection data from firestore ? Ionic Angular

Tags: angular, firebase, ionic-framework, google-cloud-firestore

Angular CLI: 13.0.4
ionic --version => 6.20.2

Hi! I'm kind of new to Ionic / Angular / Firebase.
I'm using Firebase firestore as my database, I have already created the collection and filled it with data.
What is the easiest solution to display a single document from the collection on a page ? Currently I'm stuck at writing it to the console and can't display it on the HTML. After hours of searching I hope someone can help me out with this one.

`

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
import {AngularFirestore} from "@angular/fire/compat/firestore";

@Component({
  selector: 'app-first-place',
  templateUrl: './first-place.page.html',
  styleUrls: ['./first-place.page.scss'],
})
export class FirstPlacePage implements OnInit {

  constructor(
    private router: Router,
    private afs: AngularFirestore,
    ) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.afs.collection('rentplace').valueChanges()
      .subscribe(value => console.log(value[0]));
  }
}
```

`
From the console I'm getting this output: {rentplaceTitle: 'Second page', rentplaceHref: 'secondref', rentplaceWaterBike: 44, rentplaceSup: 50, rentplaceOwnerEmail: 'xy@gmail.com', …}

I have tried cutting the array but everytime when I referred to it in the HTML I only got  as a result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just grab what you receive and display it as Json format with [JsonPipe](https://angular.io/api/common/JsonPipe) to debug your response object.

**first-place.page.html**

```
<div>
  {{content | json}}
</div>
```

**first-place.page.js**

```
.....

content: any;

ngOnInit() {
  this.afs.collection('rentplace').valueChanges()
    .subscribe(value => this.content = value);
}

.....
```

Comment: Aaa yep, this was truly easy. Thanks for your help, it worked. Have a nice day!